# Regarding Time out error in ITfoxtec Identity Saml 2.0

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I have to implement the single sign-on functionality in my project. But once I have downloaded ITfoxtec Identity Saml2 project from [Github](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2) and run the asp.net core project I have to face error like the below screen.

[image]

Please revert me on the same as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The solution contains a test identity provider (IdP) project called TestIdPCore. The other test applications in the solution are relaying parties and therefore depends on the TestIdPCore application being running before they can start.

You can either start multiple projects at the same time or ensure that TestIdPCore is running before you start another test application.

Comment: Hello,
I have started multiple projects TestIdpCore and TestWebAppCore.
Once I click on the TestWebAppCore Login link I have to face error like "Sequence contains no elements"

https://i.imgur.com/CoawPM2.png

Answer (score 0):

I have started multiple projects TestIdpCore and TestWebAppCore.
Once I click on the TestWebAppCore Login link I have to face error like "Sequence contains no elements"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aet0J.png

Comment: Moved to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66559513/sequence-contains-no-elements-error-once-i-go-from-service-provider-project-to-i