# Sequence contains no elements error once I go from Service provider Project to Identity Project

Tags: saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I'm using `ITFoxtec SAML 2.0` where I have started multiple projects; `TestIdpCore` and `TestWebAppCore`. Once I click on the `TestWebAppCore` login link, I face the error `Sequence contains no elements`.

[image]

Comment: Image link https://i.imgur.com/CoawPM2.png

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the identity provider TestIdpCore cannot find the relying party TestWebAppCore.

I think maybe the TestWebAppCore endpoint have changed or that the application is not answering.

The relying party TestWebAppCore is default exposed on https://localhost:44306/. And the relying party is configured in the identity provider TestIdpCore appsettings.json with the metadata endpoint "https://localhost:44306/metadata".

```
  "Settings": {
    "RelyingParties": [
      {
        "Metadata": "https://localhost:44327/metadata"
      },
      {
        "Metadata": "https://localhost:44306/metadata"
      },
      {
        "Metadata": "https://localhost:44307/metadata"
      },
      {
        "Metadata": "https://localhost:44308/metadata"
      },
      {
        "Metadata": "https://localhost:44309/metadata"
      }
    ]
  }
```

If the TestWebAppCore endpoint has changed you need to change the identity provider configuration.